# Is there an equivalent for MFC VERIFY() in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc, assertions

Qt has `Q_ASSERT`, which is the equivalent of MFC `ASSERT()`, but MFC also has the [VERIFY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcatwy09.aspx) macro, which behaves the same as `ASSERT()` in Debug, except for Release:

> In the Release version of MFC, VERIFY evaluates the expression but
>   does not print or interrupt the program. For example, if the
>   expression is a function call, the call will be made.

Does Qt have an equivalent for [VERIFY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcatwy09.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is missing in Qt, but it should be easy to make your own:

```
#if !defined(VERIFY)
# if !defined(QT_NO_DEBUG)
#  define VERIFY Q_ASSERT
# else
#  define VERIFY(expr)  \
    do                    \
    {                     \
        (void) (expr);    \
    } while (0)
# endif
#endif
```

Comment: So there is no equivalent that comes with Qt?

Comment: @sashoalm That I don't know (you have searched [the reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/reference-overview.html)?), but as I said, it's easy to make your own if there isn't any.

Comment: Only briefly, but I just found this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28519) asking that Q_VERIFY() be added.